# Remove [documentation] tag from documentation

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-tags

While reviewing the documentation queue, I found that there is [a documentation tag for documentation itself](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/topics). Setting aside the question of whether we need this at all, it's hardly related to the actual [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) tag. Can this be removed, or at least relocated to a different tag?

Comment: haha that's hilarious.  And I agree that this meta-stuff does not belong on Docs itself.  Makes you wonder who had the required tag score to create that topic.

Comment: FYI, one of the topics in this tag was edited by two SE employees—see [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/revisions/276).

Comment: So basically it is used to document the usage of StackDocs itself. Not a truly bad initiative really.

Comment: What's wrong with dogfooding here?

Comment: @Gimby it still isn't related to the tag it's tied to. The [documentation] tag on SO is about official (non-SO) documentation.

Comment: Meh, can we make an exception for this? It seems kind of useful, if not currently well known.

Comment: @RamenChef seems like a bit of an off-topic thing for SO-purposes to be honest.

Comment: @RamenChef Can you suggest another tag that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 5):

This tag seems to be a useful addition to documentation, since SO's documentation is the *one* thing that isn't documented anywhere else. It needs documentation, so where else?

This answer is a vote in favor of *keeping* the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/topics) on Stack Docs.

Comment: Help center maybe?